Evaluate fractions in Binomial coefficient command
I'm trying to create a new command to automatically compute fractions and differences while displaying a Binomial coefficient
\usepackage{mathtools}    

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\braces{(}{)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{ m m m m }{ \binom{#2}{#1} {\braces*{#3}}^{#1} {\braces*{#4}}^{#2-#1} }

similar to the R function pbinom(q, size, prob)
In the main document I would like to simply write 1 - \pbinom{2}{18}{1/6} and the result that I would like to achieve is
\[
    1 - \binom{18}{2} {\braces*{\frac{1}{6}}}^{2} {\braces*{\frac{5}{6}}}^{16}
\]

Is it possible to compute differences of fractions and natural numbers in LaTeX perhaps with the use of LaTeX3?

This is a working MWE:
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\braces{(}{)}
\NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{ m m m m }{ \binom{#2}{#1} {\braces*{#3}}^{#1} {\braces*{#4}}^{#2-#1} }

% pbinom(q, size, prob)
% \NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{ m m m }{ \binom{#2}{#1} { ? }^{#1} { ? }^{ ? } }

\begin{document}
\[
    1 - \pbinom{2}{18}{\frac{1}{6}}{\frac{5}{6}}
\]
% \[
%     1 - \pbinom{2}{18}{1/6}
% \]
\end{document}


The title of your question does not really match the contents as 1) the fractions are not arguments of binomial coefficient 2) there are actually no computation of fractions, e.g. something like 1/3+5/7. People visiting this page and looking at answers a.t.t.o.w. thinking they compute fractions will be disappointed.

(but now this answer does compute binomial coefficient... )

You can use \fpeval and \inteval to do computations with floating point numbers and integers, respectively. For your preferred syntax, I used two auxiliary commands for processing the argument.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\braces{(}{)}

\def\pbinomauxA#1/#2\pbinomstop{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\def\pbinomauxB#1/#2\pbinomstop{\frac{\fpeval{#2-#1}}{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{ m m m }{
  \binom{#2}{#1}
  \braces*{\pbinomauxA#3\pbinomstop}^{#1}
  \braces*{\pbinomauxB#3\pbinomstop}^{\inteval{#2-#1}}
  }

\begin{document}
\[
    1 - \pbinom{2}{18}{1/6} \qquad \pbinom{4}{7}{3.25/7.1}
\]
\end{document}



\inteval would be simpler, I guess this is only defined for integers.

@DavidCarlisle I have no idea what the OP is doing with this, but there's nothing mathematically wrong with \pbinom{2}{18}{1.25/{6.3}}. But you're right about the second use of \fpeval

This does not differ much from mbert's answer, but has the added bonus of optionally computing the probability.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xintexpr}% for binomials

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\pbinom}{ommm}
 {% #1 = optional number of decimal digits; negative for the complement
  % #2 = q
  % #3 = size
  % #4 = prob
  \nardi_pbinom:nnn {#2} {#3} {#4}
  \IfValueT{#1} { = \nardi_pbinom_compute:nnnn {#1} {#2} {#3} {#4} }
 }

\fp_new:N \l__nardi_pbinom_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nardi_pbinom:nnn
 {
  \binom{#2}{#1} \!
  \left( \__nardi_pbinom_frac_first:n {#3} \right)^{\! #1} \!
  \left( \__nardi_pbinom_frac_second:n {#3} \right)^{\! \int_eval:n { #2-#1 }}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nardi_pbinom_frac_first:n
 {
  \__nardi_pbinom_frac_first:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nardi_pbinom_frac_first:w #1 / #2 \q_stop
 {
  \frac{#1}{#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nardi_pbinom_frac_second:n
 {
  \__nardi_pbinom_frac_second:w #1 \q_stop
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__nardi_pbinom_frac_second:w #1 / #2 \q_stop
 {
  \frac{\int_eval:n {#2-#1}}{#2}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nardi_pbinom_compute:nnnn
 {
  \fp_set:Nn \l__nardi_pbinom_fp
   {
    \xintiiBinomial{#3}{#2}
    *
    (#4)^(#2)
    *
    (1-#4)^(#3-#2)
   }
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 > 0 }
   { \fp_eval:n { round(\l__nardi_pbinom_fp,#1) } } % positive
   { \fp_eval:n { round(1-\l__nardi_pbinom_fp,-#1) } } % negative
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
& \pbinom{2}{18}{1/6}
\\
& \pbinom[5]{2}{18}{1/6}
\\
& 1-\pbinom{2}{18}{1/6}
\\
& 1-\pbinom[-5]{2}{18}{1/6}
\\
& \pbinom[8]{4}{100}{1/5}
\\
& 1-\pbinom[-8]{4}{100}{1/5}
\end{align}

\end{document}

I used xintexpr for computing the binomial coefficient in order to avoid inaccuracies.
A positive optional argument computes the (direct) probability, whereas a negative one computes the complementary probability (you still have to use 1- in front of the \pbinom part.
Don't use 0 as optional argument.


What happens if I use 0 as an optional argument?

@EmanueleNardi You get a low level error message. It just makes no sense.

What we can do with plain TeX:
\def\pbinom#1#2#3{\pbinomA{#1}{#2}#3/}
\def\pbinomA#1#2#3/#4/{
   {#2\choose#1}
   {#3\overwithdelims()#4}^{#1}
   {\the\numexpr#4-#3\overwithdelims()#4}^{\the\numexpr#2-#1}
}

$$
  1 - \pbinom{2}{18}{1/6}
$$

\bye

